# How should I address having used the wrong gender title for a recruiter?

Tags: email, gender

I was applying for a job and the HR person replied to me. I replied back regarding some questions asked. From the name, I inferred that the person was a man and replied with

> Dear Mr. ABC,

Later in the day I looked up the person's profile on the internet only to discover that they are actually a woman! What should I do now? What should I say to her?

I have learned my lesson to actually look up the person in the conversation first.

Comment: @Acccumulation Be very careful with gender-neutral titles or pronouns. Virtually all of them are new, contrived or non-standard and they're only slowly gaining acceptance and recognition. "Mx" in particular seems to be a UK-specific version.

Comment: If you're sending a message to a company with a liberal culture, you'll probably have more success with using their first name.

Comment: @Acccumulation I've never heard of "Mx", I'd advise against using that.  In terms of unknown gender, I'd go with the traditional Sir/Madam.

Comment: @Acccumulation Most people would find it odd if you used Mx. I would probably be offended if someone referred to me as that. Why not just say Sir/Madam like people have been doing since the beginning of time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wouldn't make too big a thing about it.

Make sure you get it correct from now on, and apologise if they reply correcting your mistake, but I wouldn't go calling attention to it.

The same goes as far as getting any honorific (Dr, Reverend, etc) wrong.

Comment: People with names that are gender-confusing are usually quite used to the mistake and shouldn't get upset about it.  (Personally, I usually don't even bother to correct the mistake.  When I was born "Loren" was male, "Lauren" was female.  Now there is no male.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel there are still a few "Lorne"s, though.

Comment: @Acccumulation A **few**.  Wolfram Alpha says there are about 6 new ones a year.